# Host will not send ICMP "fragmentation needed" if received packet length is greater than its MTU?

Tags: networking, icmp

I'm in the middle of figuring out an MTU related issue in a network.
Lacking some knowledge, hoping to get some clarification here :)

I have a setup, where a client host (with MTU=1500 bytes configured on its NI) is sending traffic to a server host (with MTU=1400 configured on its NI).
Once in a while the client will send a packet with length greater than server host's MTU (say, 1450 bytes) with DF flag set.

Both hosts have PMTUD enabled (running `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc` returns `0`; hence DF flag), however, the client for some reason isn't learning, that it should be using lower MTU for this specific path - `ip route get %server-ip-here%` does not return any special MTU.

Both hosts are located very close to each other (in the same DC, just one router in between them) and 99.9% positive all the equipment between the two hosts are just fine with the 1450 bytes packet, so they have no reason to drop it and send ICMP "fragmentation needed" back.

It is my understanding, the packet is dropped on the server host because of the the 1400 bytes MTU its network interface.

Based on all the articles I was able to find on PMTUD, it appears such ICMP packet is sent only by the routers in between the client and the server.

**Can someone confirm my thoughts:** end hosts will not send ICMP "fragmentation needed", if they dropped incoming packet due to its length being greater, than locally configured MTU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, I could only find the RFC 1191 (Path MTU Discovery) documenting what sends an ICMP fragmentation needed:

> [2. Protocol overview](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1191#section-2)
>
> The basic idea is that a source host initially assumes that the PMTU
> of a path is the (known) MTU of its first hop, and sends all datagrams
> on that path with the DF bit set.  If any of the datagrams are too
> large **to be forwarded** without fragmentation **by some router** along the
> path, **that router** will discard them and return ICMP Destination
> Unreachable messages with a code meaning "fragmentation needed and DF
> set" [7].

> [4. Router specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1191#section-4)
>
> When a **router** is unable to **forward** a datagram because it exceeds the
> MTU of the next-hop network and its Don't Fragment bit is set, the
> router is required to return an ICMP Destination Unreachable message
> to the source of the datagram, with the Code indicating "fragmentation
> needed and DF set".

All description assume the ICMP is emitted by a router, not by an host. The decision happens just before re-emitting to the *other* interface with a too low MTU, not when receiving it.

There's no provision for an host (which isn't routing the received packet) to emit such ICMP. It would send a direct error to the application trying to *emit* such packet, but if it *received* a packet of size 1500 that it doesn't support "officially" (because its MTU is 1400), either the hardware would have dropped it (which it didn't or this would be a moot point), or if it didn't, then I guess that's undefined (in RFC) behavior and the OS network stack can accept it.

One should assume in a LAN the configurations are correct: that the host has the same MTU as all other nodes in the same broadcast domain.

Comment: Such ICMP should have been sent by the router (missed this part): did it? If not why not?

Comment: If there's a PMTUD blackhole, you can force the Linux client with MTU 1500 to behave as MTU 1400 for the problematic server (actually problematic router or client rather than server, unless router's MTU in server's LAN isn't also 1400: that would be a misconfiguration between router and server. But I guess there's a tunnel that wasn't told about) with something like: `ip route add 198.51.100.2 via 192.0.2.1 mtu 1400` (or even `mtu lock 1400` to not even do pmtud)

Comment: ICMP has never been sent by the router because it's very likely (I'm waiting for the confirmation from the team) totally fine with the packets the client is sending, i.e. router was able to accept and pass the packet onwards.

Comment: If the router on the server side has MTU 1500 and the server has MTU 1400, then the server is misconfigured. PMTUD is not meant to handle misconfiguration. Alternatively the router is misconfigured and should also have MTU 1400. Your choice.

Comment: indeed. The point was to confirm that a host is not expected to send such ICMP and I should not expect PMTUD to sort this situation out. Instead, path fixed MTU should be configured on the client to align both sides.
Appreciate the information!

Comment: Btw: the ip route setting in my 2nd comment interacts with the TCP part of the routing stack. I'm not sure anything will be done for UDP (contrary to setting the interface MTU, which can't be done or it will break the client this time): should be tested if UDP use is to be considered.